# Addressing 'Insufficient Access' When Blocking Senders in Outlook M365

Tags: active-directory, entra-id, azureadconnect

Whenever I block a sender in the Outlook M365 desktop app by right-clicking on an email and selecting "Block Sender" to move it to junk email, an error occurs in AD/Entra Connect, indicating "***insufficient access rights to perform the operation***".

[image]

[image]

I resolve this by accessing AD Users and Computers, right-clicking on my account, and navigating to:
`Properties` > `Security` tab > `Advanced` > `Restore Defaults` > `Apply` > `OK`, and then AD/Entra Connect syncs work without error.

The issue is related to the `msExchBlackedSenderHash` attribute. The problem appears to affect AD user accounts with **Domain Admins** or **Account Operators** access. However, the resolution remains consistent across all accounts, requiring the applied fix mentioned earlier.

[image]

#### Some Technical Details

- On-prem AD using Microsoft Azure AD Connect version 2.2.1.0
- Forest and domain functional levels both Windows Server 2016
- 4 domain controllers none of which are read-only across two sites/subnets
- Hybrid Entra ID/Azure AD environment, all mailboxes are on M365/Exchange Online. While we're in the process of decommissioning Exchange 2010, there's still work to be done. External emails (inbound to our domain) are currently routed directly to M365.

### Questions

- Is there a configuration in Azure AD Connect, M365, or on-premises Active Directory to prevent the 'insufficient access rights' error when blocking a sender in Outlook M365, especially for accounts with elevated privileges like Domain Admins or Account Operators?
- Is there a technical explanation for the root cause of this issue and any clarity as to why it poses a problem?

Comment: What happens when you use the Exhange Online portal or EOP PowerShell to block the sender. In M365 you don't need to block sender, if it's junk email just report it as junk email or phising, then Microsoft can update it's detections

Comment: @Turdie I have the public IPs of the security gateways which is not Microsoft added to M365 allowed IP policy or whatever it is called. So the M365 "spam" or "suspected spam" gets passed through the M365 Exchange blocking of those when that gateway sends to M365. So MX records point to security appliance gateways, they filter, etc. and then passes to M365 for the designated domain. I will test from Outlook on the web next time I have one to block and see if that makes any difference. In the meantime, the workaround I have seems to work.

Comment: That explains a lot, Outlook triggers ews and tries to block in exchange online while you need to block it in the security gateway, don't they have an outlook addin?

Comment: I can block in the gateway system but it's not as easy as the right click with Outlook to put it in Junk Email for the things that do slip thru the security appliance gateway. This is also a business that gets lots of email from a ton of emailing lists and allows a lot of BS through for business operations related to freedom of information, public services, and stuff that is normal to this sort of business and totally against censorship so there is a slew of allowed listed things in place. It's like night and day vs US Health Care industry I grew up in IT wise. I don't think there is an addin.

Comment: Then create some automation for it, like a script or a runbook. Because everything slips through eop it's useless to block it in outlook. And when you reimage a client all the blocks are gone if you do it this way. And i wouldn't block on sender that can be spoofed

Comment: I gotcha, I'll investigate further and figure out something more automated. This is more a personal thing than a business thing because to me, I will allow it to go to Junk Email, check it once a day or so with cursory look, Ctrl+A, delete, etc. This just keeps my inbox cleaner for the other important stuff. I was really more curious why AD Connect gave that error and the restore defaults fixed until the next time. I do agree there is a better solution as you are suggesting, but it's a personal thing more than for my work. A consultant gave me the workaround but never explained and gone now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that your user account is a member of a protected group. As a result, permissions inheritance is disabled on your user account and the AdminSDHolder security descriptor ACL is applied to your user account, as well as having the adminCount attribute set to 1. Therefore, Entra ID Connect doesn't have the permissions it needs on your user account. This isn't a configuration issue or a problem with Entra ID Connect and there isn't anything you can do in Entra ID Connect to resolve this.

The fix is to remove your user account from all protected groups, clear the adminCount attribute, and re-enable permissions inheritance on your user account.

Best practive dictates that you have a separate user account for administrative tasks and not include your "day-to-day" user account in any protected groups or roles.

Comment: While this is all accurate. The user can modify the AdminSDHolder (Using AdsiEdit) permissions which will replicate to all of the protected accounts - essentially solving this issue. Probably not recommended, but sometimes needed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/security-best-practices/appendix-c--protected-accounts-and-groups-in-active-directory

Protected accounts are already problematic with Entra ID Connect because Entra ID Connect can also not write back to those user accounts - even though when installed, Entra ID Connect updates root level perms.

Comment: I figured it had to do with the `AdminSDHolder` thing and the protected accounts. Unfortunately for these domains and the tasks that are done everyday by all the accounts which are classified as protected, it's not really practical easily to make that sort of change per workflows, etc. I'm literally the only person that even notices this issue though and have been working around it for a while now as per the other workaround I mentioned. I appreciate the answer and will dig into that more too.

Comment: @Appleoddity True, the AdminSDHolder ACL can be modified but that isn't something I would generally recommend. Additionally, modifying the AdminSDHolder ACL would likely trigger any EDR/XDR solution that may be in place and would probably be more trouble than it's worth. That being said, thanks for adding some additional clarity.